# Firebase/React/Redux Component has weird updating behavior, state should be ok

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am having a chat web app which is connected to firebase.

[image: Flickering lastMessage]

When I refresh the page the lastMessage is loaded (as the gif shows), however, for some reason, if the component is otherwise mounted the lastMessage sometimes flickers and disappears afterwards like it is overridden. When I hover over it, and hence update the component, the lastMessage is there. 
This is a weird behavior and I spent now days trying different things.

I would be very grateful if someone could take a look as I am really stuck here.

The db setup is that on firestore the chat collection has a sub-collection messages.

App.js

```
// render property doesn't re-mount the MainContainer on navigation

const MainRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      <MainContainer>
        <Component {...props} />
      </MainContainer>
    )}
  />
);

render() {
  return (
   ...
    <MainRoute
      path="/chats/one_to_one"
      exact
      component={OneToOneChatContainer}
    />
```

```
// on refresh the firebase user info is retrieved again

class MainContainer extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    const { user, getUserInfo, firebaseAuthRefresh } = this.props;
    const { isAuthenticated } = user;    
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getUserInfo(user.id);
      firebaseAuthRefresh();
    } else {
      history.push("/sign_in");
    }
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation {...this.props} />
        <Main {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Action

```
// if I set a timeout around fetchResidentsForChat this delay will make the lastMessage appear...so I must have screwed up the state / updating somewhere. 

const firebaseAuthRefresh = () => dispatch => {
  firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem("firebaseUid", user.uid);

      dispatch(setFirebaseAuthUser({uid: user.uid, email: user.email}))
      dispatch(fetchAllFirebaseData(user.projectId));
    }
  });
};

export const fetchAllFirebaseData = projectId => dispatch => {
  const userId = localStorage.getItem("firebaseId");
  if (userId) {
    dispatch(fetchOneToOneChat(userId));
  }
  if (projectId) {
    // setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(fetchResidentsForChat(projectId));
    // }, 100);
...


export const fetchOneToOneChat = userId => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestOneToOneChat());
  database
    .collection("chat")
    .where("userId", "==", userId)
    .orderBy("updated_at", "desc")
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      let oneToOne = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let messages = [];
        doc.ref
          .collection("messages")
          .orderBy("created_at")
          .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(message => {
              messages.push({ id: message.id, ...message.data() });
            });
          });
        oneToOne.push(Object.assign({}, doc.data(), { messages: messages }));
      });
      dispatch(fetchOneToOneSuccess(oneToOne));
    });
};
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  residents: [],
  oneToOne: []
};
function firebaseChat(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
   case FETCH_RESIDENT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        residents: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
   case FETCH_ONE_TO_ONE_CHAT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        oneToOne: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
...
```

Main.js

```
 // ...
 render() {
   return (...
     <div>{React.cloneElement(children, this.props)}</div>
   )
 }
```

OneToOne Chat Container

```
// without firebaseAuthRefresh I don't get any chat displayed. Actually I thought having it inside MainContainer would be sufficient and subscribe here only to the chat data with fetchOneToOneChat.
// Maybe someone has a better idea or point me in another direction.

class OneToOneChatContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { firebaseAuthRefresh, firebaseData, fetchOneToOneChat } = this.props;
    const { user } = firebaseData;
    firebaseAuthRefresh();
    fetchOneToOneChat(user.id || localStorage.getItem("firebaseId"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OneToOneChat {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}
```

```
export default class OneToOneChat extends Component {
  render() {
    <MessageNavigation
              firebaseChat={firebaseChat}
              firebaseData={firebaseData}
              residents={firebaseChat.residents}
              onClick={this.selectUser}
              selectedUserId={selectedUser && selectedUser.residentId}
            />
  }
}
```

```
export default class MessageNavigation extends Component {
  render() {
      const {
      onClick,
      selectedUserId,
      firebaseChat,
      firebaseData
    } = this.props;
    <RenderResidentsChatNavigation
            searchChat={this.searchChat}
            residents={residents}
            onClick={onClick}
            firebaseData={firebaseData}
            firebaseChat={firebaseChat}
            selectedUserId={selectedUserId}
          />
  }
}

const RenderResidentsChatNavigation = ({
 residents,
  searchChat,
  selectedUserId,
  onClick,
  firebaseData,
  firebaseChat
}) => (
 <div>
 {firebaseChat.oneToOne.map(chat => {
        const user = residents.find(
          resident => chat.residentId === resident.residentId
        );
        const selected = selectedUserId == chat.residentId;
        if (!!user) {
          return (
            <MessageNavigationItem
              id={chat.residentId}
              key={chat.residentId}
              chat={chat}
              onClick={onClick}
              selected={selected}
              user={user}
              firebaseData={firebaseData}
            />
          );
        }
      })}
  {residents.map(user => {
          const selected = selectedUserId == user.residentId;
          const chat = firebaseChat.oneToOne.find(
            chat => chat.residentId === user.residentId
          );
          if (_isEmpty(chat)) {
            return (
              <MessageNavigationItem
                id={user.residentId}
                key={user.residentId}
                chat={chat}
                onClick={onClick}
                selected={selected}
                user={user}
                firebaseData={firebaseData}
              />
            );
          }
      })}
  </div>
  }
}
```

And lastly the item where the lastMessage is actually displayed

```
export default class MessageNavigationItem extends Component {
render() {
    const { hovered } = this.state;
    const { user, selected, chat, isGroupChat, group, id } = this.props;
    const { messages } = chat;
    const item = isGroupChat ? group : user;
    const lastMessage = _last(messages);
 return (
   <div>
     {`${user.firstName} (${user.unit})`}
     {lastMessage && lastMessage.content}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was an async setup issue.

In the action 'messages' are a sub-collection of the collection 'chats'.
To retrieve them it is an async operation.

When I returned a Promise for the messages of each chat and awaited for it before I run the success dispatch function, the messages are shown as expected.